# jQuery .ajax post fails with large JSON object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I am posting JSON data to an ASP.NET MVC2 server.  I am posting large JSON strings (which incorporate a base64-encoded file stream, read from the local file system).  The jQuery ajax call works fine up to file sizes of around 2.5Mb.  Once above this size the ajax call fails (never gets to the controller).  I can't detect exactly what the error is - it doesn not seem to populate the error variables.

The ajax call is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 10000,
            url: "/Molecule/SaveMolecule",
            data: { jsonpost: postdata, moleculetype: _moleculeType, moleculefilestream: _moleculefilestream, changedproducts: stringifiedChangedProducts }, // NOTE the moleculeType being added here
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.rc == "success") {
                    $.log('ServerSuccess:' + data.message);

                    molecule_updateLocalInstance();

                    _bMoleculeIsDirty = false;
                    if (bReturnToMoleculeList != null && bReturnToMoleculeList == true) {
                        navigator_Go('/Molecule/Index/' + _moleculeType);
                    }
                    else {
                        _saveMoleculeButtonFader = setTimeout(function () {

                            $('#profilesave-container').delay(500).html('<img src="/content/images/tick.png" width="32px" height="32px" /><label>' + _moleculeSingularTerm + ' was saved</label>').fadeIn(500);

                            _saveMoleculeButtonFader = setTimeout(function () { $('#profilesave-container').fadeOut(1000); }, 2000);

                        }, 500);
                    }

                } else {
                    $.log('ServerUnhappy:' + data.message);
                    RemoveMoleculeExitDialog();
                }
            }
            , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Save failed, check console for error message:' +textStatus+' '+ errorThrown);
                MarkMoleculeAsDirty();
                $.log('Molecule Save Error:' + helper_objectToString(textStatus+' '+errorThrown));
            }
        });
```

where _moleculefilestream is the large base64-encoded stream.

My web.config includes the following:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Anyone got any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the httpRuntime's maxRequestLength property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

You can set it via a location tag to just the controller/action you need.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

The a`spnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` element must be added to the `<appSettings>` section of your **web.config** file, setting to **2147483647** which is the equivalent of the maximum value of an `Int32` data type.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In this page of the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx), you will be able to find all the information about the elements as well as their use.

Note: In the section of the official documentation it is recommended not to adjust to the maximum value since it represents a security risk. Ideally, you should check the number of items you want to deserialize and try to estimate based on the maximum json size you are using.

Original post by @Flxtr: [Here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105557/como-enviar-una-lista-grande-de-objetos-json-mediante-una-petici%C3%B3n-ajax-con-jque)

**OLD**

If you want to upload a file, why not try using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

For example:

```js
function getDataForm() {

    var data = new FormData();

    var files = fileUploader.get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("File", files[0]);
    }
    data.append("ImagePath", "");

    data.append("Id", ImageId);
    data.append("Name", txtName.val().trim());
    data.append("Description", txtDescription.val().trim());

    return data;
}

function save(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Files/SaveImage",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {

            if (response.success) {
                $.showMessage(messages.NAME, messages.SUCCESS, "success");
                closeForm();
                Files.ImageList.gridImages.ajax.reload();
            }
            else {
                $.showMessage(messages.NAME, response.message, "error");
            };

            btnSave.button('reset');
        },
        error: function (request, status, exception) {
            $.showMessage(messages.NAME, exception, "error");
            btnSave.button('reset');
        }
    });
};
```

Then, on the server side, change the request length in web config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="65536"/>
```

For example:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="65536"/>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
        <error statusCode="401" redirect="/Error/401" />
        ...
        <error statusCode="411" redirect="/Error/411" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Also, change the parameter `processData` to `false` in the ajax request:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/Security/SavePermissions",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(pStrPermissions),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            panel.showAlert("Permisos", "Se han actualizado correctamente los permisos.", "success");
            resetForm();
        }
        else {
            $.showMessage("Permisos", response.message, "error");
        };
    },
    error: function (request, status, exception) {
        $.showMessage("Permisos", exception, "error");
    }
});
```

These are just suggestions. The only thing that actually worked for me was to serialize the list and deserialize it on the server.

For example, on the client side:

```js
function savePermissions(pLstObjPermissions) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Security/SavePermissions",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ pStrPermissions: JSON.stringify(pLstObjPermissions)}) ,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                panel.showAlert("Permisos", "Se han actualizado correctamente los permisos.", "success");
                resetForm();
            }
            else {
                $.showMessage("Permisos", response.message, "error");
            };
        },
        error: function (request, status, exception) {
            $.showMessage("Permisos", exception, "error");
        }
    });
};
```

On the server side:

```
public ActionResult SavePermissions(string pStrPermissions)
{
    var lLstObjResult = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    try
    {
        SecurityFactory.GetPermissionService().UpdateList(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Permission>>(pStrPemissions));
        lLstObjResult.Add(MESSAGE, "Registro guardado exitosamente");
        lLstObjResult.Add(SUCCESS, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        lLstObjResult.Add(MESSAGE, e.Message);
        lLstObjResult.Add(SUCCESS, false);
    }

    return Json(lLstObjResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I know that this is not the best way, but it works until something better comes along.

If you have a better way to resolve this problem, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adjusting the timeout? 10 secs might be enough for 2.5Mb but not more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Erick - I'm testing this locally, so 10s is plenty for large files, but I take your point for the live environment and will bump up the timeout accordingly.